# Django import ignores sys.path

Tags: django, python-import

A unit test module stored in `/tmp` is imported in my Django project. The unit test module begins like this:

```py
import tempfile
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, tempfile.gettempdir()) # /tmp is first in sys.path

from name_like_app import foo             # foo is the function to test
                                          # name_like_app.py is in /tmp
                                          # The import looks in the app instead of /tmp!
```

The module containing `foo` is stored in `/tmp`, but happens to be named like one of the apps in my Django project. For some reason, Django looks in the app and ignores `sys.path`. Why does this happen?